# text based battleship game: How can i access and add values to a dictionary which is stored in a class from a function which is not in that same class

Tags: python, dictionary

Unfortunately, I have no coding experience. For my first task in coding class i recieved a framework for the battleship game (only board and some dictionaries) and I have to program the rest of the game. I have somehow managed to draw the ships on the board but i can not find a way to add the values to the dictionary which should store all of the ship coordinates.

```py
class GameData():
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.last_coordinates = ""
        self.player1_turn = True
        self.ships_player1 = {
            "aircraftcarrier": {"start": "", "end": "", "orientation": Orientation.horizontal, "hits": []}, \
            "battleship": {"start": "", "end": "", "orientation": Orientation.horizontal, "hits": []}, \
            "cruiser": {"start": "", "end": "", "orientation": Orientation.horizontal, "hits": []}, \
            "destroyer1": {"start": "", "end": "", "orientation": Orientation.horizontal, "hits": []}, \
            "destroyer2": {"start": "", "end": "", "orientation": Orientation.horizontal, "hits": []}, \
            "submarine1": {"start": "", "end": "", "orientation": Orientation.horizontal, "hits": []}, \
            "submarine2": {"start": "", "end": "", "orientation": Orientation.horizontal, "hits": []} \
            }
```

The first and last coordinates the user inputs should be stored in that dictionary. The input() is in a different function outside the class GameData

Comment: Hello @marakash to SO! You can google for `python dictionary manipulation` if you want to know how to work with dictionaries in python.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you create an instance of the GameData class:

```
gd = GameData()
```

You can just access the filds within such instance like:

```
something = gd.ships_player1["aircraftcarrier"]["start"]
```

Or add/set items of such dictionary:

```
gd.ships_player1["submarine3"] = something
```

Comment: Thank you! The adding works but after calling the same function again and adding new values to another key the first values are gone. What could ne the issue here?

Comment: Are you sure you create the instance only once, and do not explicitly overwrite the values?